# Is there a way to synchronize clocks with the Microsoft Band using the SDK?

Tags: android, microsoft-band

I'm working on a project where I need sensor data readings from the Band and a connected smartphone to be synchronized. Thus, I need to be able to find out the clock difference between both devices. Events contain a timestamp, which I could use for synchronization, but this would require a way to reliably force the Band to send a sensor reading *directly* on request.

1. The smartphone requests a sensor reading from the Band (f.e. by registering an event listener) and notes the local time `t1` of the request transmission
2. The Band receives the request and directly responds to it, sending its local timestamp `s1`
3. The smartphone receives the response at local time `t2`.

Now, the smartphone can approximate the connection delay `d = (t2 - t1)/2` and can set its local time to `s1 + d` to approximately synchronize with the Band. This protocol only works properly if the Band responds within a reasonable time.

Does `getSensorManager().registerXXXEventListener()` behave like this or is there  a possibility that it delays the response (f.e. to save energy)? If it may introduce delays, is there some other way to get the Band's current time?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an automatic synchronization. If you set the clock of the band to some other time and print the timestamp of the SDK you will notice that it corresponds to the phone time, not the band time.
So I guess there is no need for time synchronization between phone and band.

Comment: I think the SDK simply reports the receive time on the phone as the timestamp, but since the SDK is closed-source, I don't have a good way to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a sensor and hook the appropriate timestamp?  Don't have band with me but I believe ISensorReading:: Timestamp comes from the device?

As defined, pulled out of object browser...

Let us know if this works...

```
namespace Microsoft.Band.Sensors
{
public class BandSensorReadingEventArgs<T> : EventArgs where T : IBandSensorReading
{
    public BandSensorReadingEventArgs(T reading);

    public T SensorReading { get; }
}
}
```

System.DateTimeOffset **Timestamp** { get; } Member of Microsoft.Band.Sensors.IBandSensorReading

```
    private async void HeartRate_ReadingChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandHeartRateReading> e)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            TextBlock_HeartBeatStatus.Text = e.SensorReading.HeartRate.ToString();
            DateTimeOffset timestamp = e.SensorReading.Timestamp;
        });
    }
    private async void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading> e)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            string status = 
            $"x:{e.SensorReading.AccelerationX.ToString("F1")} y:{e.SensorReading.AccelerationY.ToString("F1")} z:{e.SensorReading.AccelerationZ.ToString("F1")}";       
            TextBlock_AccelStatus.Text = status;
        });
        DateTimeOffset timestamp = e.SensorReading.Timestamp();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, sensor readings include a timestamp, but the clock of the Band might have a different value than the smartphone's clock at the same point in time. That makes it hard to match up sensor readings from the smartphone with sensor readings from the Band.

Thus, a way to synchronize the clocks would make matched up data more accurate. The protocol I've described in my initial question is basically (S)NTP.

Comment: I was addressing "is there some other way to get the Band's current time".  No way to set the time remotely or sync it with the web at this point.